# Why breakpoint in a static constructor doesn't get hit even though code gets executed, in this specific case?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-debugging

This is a simple reproducible solution in Visual Studio.
A class library project has one Customer class as shown below.
A test project has one test class and method as shown below.
The Customer static constructor has a breakpoint in it.
The first statement in TestMethod1 has another breakpoint.

When I run TestMethod1 in debug mode, its breakpoint gets hit as expected. However when I hit F11 many times or continue running, the breakpoint in the constructor doesn't get hit and the debugger doesn't go into the constructor. The constructor code runs because name variable in TestMethod1 has the value 'John'.

If I remove the breakpoint in TestMethod1, the breakpoint in the constructor gets hit.

I don't understand this behavior. Am I missing something or is this a bug in the debugger?
using VS 2022 Pro 17.7.4.

UPDATE:
I tried this in Jetbrains Rider and it works as expeced. It always breaks into the static constructor whether there's a breakpoint in TestMethod or not. So I guess this is an issue with VS.

```
namespace SomeLibrary
{
    public  class Customer
    {
        public static readonly Customer SomeCustomer;
        public static string name;
        
        
        private Customer()
        {
            }

        static Customer()
        {
            SomeCustomer = new Customer();
            name = "John";
        }

        public static void SomeMethod()
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using SomeLibrary;

namespace TestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            
            Customer.SomeCustomer.ToString();
            Customer.SomeMethod();

            string name = Customer.name;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you switch between different Git branches while you experience this? Sometimes I have some unexpected behaviour with breakpoints after switiching between branches.

Comment: @MustafaÖzçetin I don't switch between branches. I added an update. The issues doesn't happen in Rider.

Comment: Perhaps its best to log an issue on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio (or check to see if its been logged already)

Comment: Tried to reproduce and I can't.  Visual Studio 17.7.3 and 17.7.4 Enterprise edition works fine.  Tested with MSTest adapter and framework versions  2.1.1 and 3.1.1.  ‍♂️

Comment: Your post caught my attention and when I tried them with exact same code lines, the breakpoint behaved strangely for me too. I uploaded a [test video](https://i.imgur.com/CQkWpWo.mp4). Could you please review it and let me know if we are experiencing the same issue or not?

Comment: @gurkan Yeah it looks like you're experiencing the same issue.  The static constructor breakpoint doesn't get hit even though the code is executed.

Comment: @Timothy G. I tried VS 17.7.4 pro and enterprise with .Net core 3.1 and got my behavior. Someone else here is experiencing what I experienced.  Maybe it's a VS setting that's in play.

Comment: This looks like a VS issue, you could create a ticket via this: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report

Comment: @Tony_Henrich I don't think this [issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/c-cant-step-instep-out-properly-while-in-static-co/638510) is specific to the version. Microsoft Team does not seem to be very interested as in similar issues :) I think it has to do with [static constructors not being callable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors#remarks). Visual Studio was should be able to handle this situation, but it cannot.

Comment: For what it's worth, my test was using .NET 7

Comment: @Bowman Zhu-MSFT I created a ticket a few days ago, https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Breakpoint-in-static-constructor-doesnt/10476066

Answer (score 1):

Did you add anything of Customer at Watch tab in debugger?

In my case, if I watch any element of `Customer` (i.e. Customer.SomeCustomer) and set breakpoint at TestMethod1, breakpoint inside static constructor doesn't get hit.

I think this is because VS Debugger performs `Customer constructor` before TestMethod1 call it. Since `Customer constructor` is static constructor which can be called at most once, and called by VS Debugger Process, breakpoint won't be hit

If you turn off breakpoint at TestMethod1, VS Debugger won't access to Watch Values, breakpoint at 'Customer constructor' can be hit

---

I assume that program that you are debugging and VS Debugger are identical process, but debugger can access and execute that program's code.

Suppose that you set a breakpoint at `Customer.SomeCustomer.ToString();` and watch `Customer.SomeCustomer` in debugger tab.

This is my scenario.

1. Breakpoint at `Customer.SomeCustomer.ToString();` get hit
2. VS Debugger try to find every value at `Watch` tab ( including `Customer.SomeCustomer`)
3. Since `Customer`'s static constructor wasn't executed yet in your program, VS Debugger Process will execute it.
4. (This is the point) Breakpoint can be hit only if your program execute that line.
   At this time, Debugger process execute static constructor so breakpoint won't be hit.
5. What Debugger process executed will assigned to static variable (`Customer.SomeCustomer`).
6. After continue pressed, `Customer.SomeCustomer.ToString();` will not call static constructor, because `Customer.SomeCustomer` already has value

If you remove the breakpoint in TestMethod1, static constuctor will executed by your program not by VS Debugger because debugger find values at `Watch` tab only when breakpoint get hit.

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to say. The breakpoint in the constructor gets hit or not depending on if there's that specific breakpoint in TestMethod1. I don't get what the relationship between the two breakpoints is to make the debugger behave differently.
I expect the breakpoint in the constructor to always get hit.. at some point.

Comment: I add some detailes and scenario. sorry for my poor engilsh

Comment: See my update in my question. I don't understand your statements about the debugger process and watch window. The execution of a program should not matter whether the debugger and breakpoints are being used or not.